# Do I need to limit logic current into this SSR

Tags: solid-state-relay

This Opto22 OAC5 (datasheet link below) relay has a logic input current of 12mA. I am building a transformer/rectifier to feed the logic switch. Can I just connect the power to the input or does it have to be current limited? I dont know how that all works or how to limit the current if that is needed.

Any advice appreciated, thank you.

https://www.opto22.com/products/oac15

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect your power (nominal 5V, 15V or 24V) directly to the input because this module has an internal resistor (Rc) that limits the current.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The [datasheet](http://documents.opto22.com/0449_Std_Dig_AC_Outputs_data_sheet.pdf) (which is what you should have linked to rather than the catalog page) shows that the '15' is the nominal logic input voltage, 15 V.*

Since it is specified to work on a 9 - 16 V input your 12 V supply should be fine **if** it is a smoothed supply. (It will need a smoothing capacitor otherwise you'll be switching the input on an off at twice mains frequency.) Check the power-supply voltage before you connect up.

Comment: Thanks.  Just to clarify my relay is an OAC5, 2.5 - 8 vdc input.

If I have it right, looks like from your reply that I do not need to regulate the current to the primary side of this relay. I can just take the smoothed rectified power that is within the input voltage range and switch that and that will not harm the relay.

Comment: That should be fine.